# SPFx - Increment Like in sharepoint list item rating

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I have a SharePoint list with reviews enabled, I am trying to patch an increment to the like count within SPFx.

What's the best way to achieve this? Can't find much info online, can anyone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE:**

You can use SP PnP JS library to like/unlike list items/site pages < Seems to be broken.

---

When trying to do a post request using the old rest api, I get this error:

```
this.props.context.spHttpClient.post("https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.SetLike(listID=%27%7B1E5C322E%2D00EB%2D4A58%2D8545%2D942D2AD5FB11%7D%27,itemID=%2713%27,like=true"
```

"The expression "Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.SetLike(listID='{1E5C322E-00EB-4A58-8545-942D2AD5FB11}',itemID='13',like=true" is not valid."

I think this only works for SharePoint server not online.

---

Update

Using this method worked!!!

**Another Approach: Using JSOM in SPFx:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SP PnP JS library to like/unlike list items/site pages.

**Example**:

```
import { sp, IItem } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";
import "@pnp/sp/comments/item";
import { ILikeData, ILikedByInformation } from "@pnp/sp/comments";

// get a specific item by id.
let item: IItem = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("My List").items.getById(1).get();

// like an item
await item.like();

// unlike an item
await item.unlike();
```

**Documentation**: [@pnp/sp/comments and likes](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/comments-likes/#like)

---

**Update**:

Seems like you can also use old endpoints like:

```
/_api/Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.SetLike(listID=@a1,itemID=@a2,like=@a3)
```

**Source**: [Likes are not supported in this item](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/1498)

---

Also, you can try this approach of getting like count & liked by information from list item and then update list item with new like/unlike:

[How to like/unlike resource via SharePoint REST API](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/cdaaf82007b7bbb266da377b5d2a2f29)

---

**Another Approach: Using JSOM in SPFx**:

First of all, load JSOM modules in your web part as given here: [Connect to SharePoint using the JavaScript Object Model (JSOM)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-sharepoint-using-jsom)

Then use below function to set like/unlike on list item:

```
export function likeUnlikeListItem(listName: string, itemId: number, isLike: boolean) {
  Promise.resolve().then(
    () => {
      sp.web.lists
        .getByTitle(listName)
        .get()
        .then(
          (data) => {
            Promise.resolve().then(
              () => {
                // eslint-disable-next-line
                SP.SOD.registerSod(
                  "reputation.js",
                  "/_layouts/15/reputation.js",
                );
                // eslint-disable-next-line
                SP.SOD.executeFunc(
                  "reputation.js",
                  "Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation",
                  () => {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    const spContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

                    const listId = data.Id;
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setLike(
                      spContext,
                      listId,
                      itemId,
                      isLike,
                    );
                    spContext.executeQueryAsync(
                      (data) => {
                        return true;
                      },
                      (error) => {
                        return false;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              (error) => {
                // error
                console.log(error);
                return false;
              },
            );
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            return false;
          },
        );
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    },
  );
}
```

**Usage**:

To Like list item:

```
likeUnlikeListItem("My List", 1, true);
```

To Unlike list item:

```
likeUnlikeListItem("My List", 1, false);
```

Comment: Hi @Ganesh, I have tried implement that this morning but I think this part of the library is broken/unfinished. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628705/spfx-pnp-sp-v2-0-0-item-like-is-not-a-function/69523007#69523007

Comment: Any other ways I might get like functionality to work?

Comment: Which version of PnP JS library you are using? I can see the `like()` function in 2.0.6 version.

Comment: I'm using: "@pnp/sp": "^2.9.0",

Comment: sp.web.currentUser.get() < This works so my set up must be correct

Comment: Try using updated code in my answer & see if it works for you. meanwhile I will check if there are any traditional REST APIs available for this.

Comment: Unfortunately same error: uncaught (in promise) TypeError: item.like is not a function.

I couldent find a graph call that would like an item either.

Hope you have more luck :D

Comment: I have tried to implement the old rest call, but getting an error. Could you please take a look?

Comment: I have tried both methods no luck :(

Comment: Hi @BennKingy, "Using JSOM in SPFx" approach is not working for you (I am using the same code in my current project & it works fine for me)? let me know if you need any help with this.

Comment: that would be much-appericated! I will try implement the "Using JSOM in SPFx" approach again now and let you know how I get on. Thank you.

Comment: I got it working!!! The issue was I wasen't loading import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all"; after all the requires :D

Comment: Ah right. glad it is working for you now.

Comment: Thanks for the help <3

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ganesh Sanap. I couldn't use .like() method for sharepoint online. But this method works
in your link
[How to like/unlike resource via SharePoint REST API](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/cdaaf82007b7bbb266da377b5d2a2f29)

```
 var likesCount=item["LikesCount"]??0;
 var likedUsers=item["LikedByStringId"];
 var userKeys = likedUsers.results==null?[]:likedUsers.results;
 const userId = window["_spPageContextInfo"]?.userId?? (await 
 pnp.sp.web.currentUser.get()).Id;
 userKeys.push(userId.toString());
 await pnp.sp.web.lists.getById(this.listId).items.getById(itemId).update({
        LikedByStringId:{results:userKeys},/*userId value aray*/
        LikesCount:likesCount
      });
```